# Tweepy: tweepy.Client output 403 Forbidden with valid tokens

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently doing a sentiment analysis on Twitter based on hashtags.

My problem is that when I'm trying to fetch the list of tweets I'm getting a 403 forbidden.

I already have an app registered in the developer page of Twitter and I also regenerated my tokens thinking that they were not valid anymore. But I keep having this output

I also did read that Twitter ended free API access, but I don't know if it's true because the changes adopted for Twitter are kind of a mess to follow. In that case it would make sense that I receive this 403.

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/main.py", line 151, in <module>
    results = interpret_results(user_query)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/main.py", line 63, in interpret_results
    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query, tweet_fields=["text"], max_results=100)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tweepy/client.py", line 1266, in search_recent_tweets
    return self._make_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tweepy/client.py", line 129, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tweepy/client.py", line 100, in request
    raise Forbidden(response)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
```

### Simplified version of the code

```py
consumer_key = config["CONSUMER_KEY"]
consumer_secret = config["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
access_token = config["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
access_token_secret = config["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
bearer = config["BEARER"]

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=consumer_key,
                       consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
                       access_token=access_token,
                       access_token_secret=access_token_secret,
                       bearer_token=bearer)

client.search_recent_tweets(query, tweet_fields=["text"], max_results=100)
```